# CheckBox Column Do Not Works After execute grid.view.render function

Tags: gridview, extjs, checkbox

On a  ExtJS 3 grid I have executed the next orders:

```
// grid is a GridPanel
// data is a grid column configuration
grid.applyState(data);
grid.view.render();
```

The grid panel has a checkbox column and after that two lines, the 'select all' rows with the checkbox do not works.

Has somebody have the same problem? Thanks

Comment: Can you please give complete code or any make any fiddler for this.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.